# Language specification for Juttle?

Tags: specifications, juttle

Juttle seems similar to a query language like SQL, but also seems to contain summation, time-series batching, and graphing capabilities. Is there full documentation on the language somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jut publishes the Juttle documentation here:

http://juttle.github.io/juttle/